# Implement a search procedure in terms of a set test procedure

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms

Suppose you have a procedure $\mathrm{Prod}(S, t)$ that inputs a finite set of integers $S$ and an integer target $t$, and outputs either “yes” or “no” according to whether there exist distinct elements $x_1, \dots, x_n \in S$ with $\prod_{i=1}^n x_i = t$. You would like to implement an enhanced version of $\mathrm{Prod}(S, t)$, called $\mathrm{ProdSearch}(S, t)$ that outputs the elements $x_1, \dots, x_n$ if such elements exist.

Describe an efficient such procedure $\mathrm{ProdSearch}$ that works by making multiple calls to $\mathrm{Prod}$ as a sub-routine. Carefully explain why your procedure is correct.​

Comment: Do you know how to solve the corresponding problem for SUBSET-SUM?

Comment: Hi, I roughly understand what they are looking for, but I have absolutely no idea how to begin here. And nope, I don't know how to solve for SUBSET-SUM. Thanks!

Comment: The question has been asked before with respect to SUBSET-SUM, but due to the useless search capabilities of the site, I am unable to find it. The solution is the same.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Google is often the best way to search Stack Exchange, but it isn't a silver bullet (no tags, pollution by titles in the “Related” sidebar, …). You may want to leave feedback on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277584/feedback-requested-search-engine-usage.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Suppose you asked your oracle whether there is a subset of $\{x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$ whose product is $t$. What can you deduce if the answer is YES? What can you deduce if the answer is NO?

Here is the full solution:

> If the oracle answers YES, we deduce that we can remove $x_1$ from $S$. If the oracle answers NO, we deduce that every solution must contain $x_1$. We therefore remove $x_1$ from $S$ and update our target product to $t/x_1$. Continuing in this vein for $n-1$ more iterations, we find a solution. This requires at most $n$ calls to $\mathsf{Prod}$ in total.

Comment: I would deduce that `Prod` would be far better returning the set of matching numbers itself, rather than have `ProdSearch` calling `Prod` just to perform the boolean test and then progressively eliminating elements until an exact match is found.  The repeated calls to `Prod` would be somewhat wasteful.

Comment: You can see a summary of the full solution in the updated version of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, i'm going to solve this problem. But only this time, next time do it yourself:

Follow this procedure:

- call the function prod(s,t)
- if it says no, there is no such subset and you are done.
- if it says yes do this:

in pseudocode

```
var boolean = true;
array numbers // this is the set of your question
while(boolean)
{
boolean = false;
for(int i = 0;i<n;i++)
{
  var numbers2[numbers-1];//We are going to create an array(subset) with    all numbers less 1
  for(int j=i;j<numbers.size;j++)
  {
   if(i != j)
    numbers2[j] = numbers[i];
  }
  if(prod(numbers2,t) == "yes")
 {
   numbers = numbers2 //If it says yes then the number  on the set is not part of the subset we are looking for, we eliminate it
   boolean = true;//As we can keep eliminating numbers we are not over yet
  }

}
}
```

I hope is clear  enough, this is prodsearch. As an aside, with aslightly modified version of this algorithm, you could solve an np-complete problem in polynomial time if you have sum instead of prod

Comment: You have to add "return numbers" to the end

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. This is a [questions and answers site](http://cs.stackexchange.com/tour), not a discussion or support forum. We write answers not just for the asker, but also for all future visitors with a similar question. Please don't remove your contribution based on your perception of the asker's motivations: over time, the asker is only a small proportion of your audience.